# How to pass data based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I have a page that can choose to email a single file or tick a few files and email them. They both called this page `email.jsp` with their respective JavaScript function.

Email.jsp:

```
 String files=null;
        String url=null;
        String id=null;
        String hash=null;
        String[] array=null;
        String[] split=null;


        if(multiemail.equals("no")) {

           //get parameters from email()


           files= request.getParameter("filename");
            url = request.getParameter("link");
            id = request.getParameter("id");
            hash = request.getParameter("hash");

       }else{

            split = request.getParameter("link").split(",",0);
            array = request.getParameter("arrayList").split(",",0);

        }
```

This means that if it's a single email,get that four parameters and if it's multi email, get the two parameters.So far it's okay. Now, once I get the attributes, I want to pass the parameters to `sendemail.jsp` to process the data.

So my send button will call `sendmessage()` function:

```
$.ajax({

               url: 'sendemail.jsp',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {
                   recipient: recipient,
                   subject: subject,
                   content: content,
                   id:"<%=id%>",
                   hash:"<%=hash%>"


               },

               success: function (data) {
                   alert("Successfully initiated email to queue");
               },
               error: function (request, error) {
                   alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(error));
               }
           });
```

So in this ajax, it's basically passing data based on if it's a single email. Sure it will work. But if I'm sending multi email and clicking the same send button,it will pass on this same data to next page but it doesn't require `id` and `hash` as you can see from my email.jsp.

Now, I don't know if there's a workaround this. Is there a way that I can pass data based on conditions?

Comment: Why don't you consider initialising the object outside the ajax and add the id and hash keys based on the condition? Then you could use this object as data

Comment: Why do you have different data formats depending on how many files are selected?  Just use the same format whether 0, 1, or many files are selected.  (Hint: Arraylists can contain 1 element and still be an arraylist.)  Basically, instead of trying to over-complicate your code to handle poorly constructed data structures, use a better data structure and keep the code simple.

Comment: @David I don't follow your question

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I initialized my object outside ajax and use if condition to specify the id/hash.Then pass data object to ajax. In the other page,do I retrieve that particular data the same way like `request.getparameter`?

Comment: @Daredevil, by other page, do you mean `Email.jsp?`

Comment: i mean `sendemail.jsp` because i am passing the data to there,

Comment: @Daredevil: It’s simple... You’re constructing two different data structures based on a condition.  Why?  What’s the difference between the two and why is that difference necessary in the first place?

Comment: @David Because the first data structure calls a different function than the second. Why do I do it that way and not use the same data structure? Because the second data structure requires me to checked checkbox of multiple files while another one does not require to do so. I hope this is clear.

Comment: @Daredevil: Is all seems very unnecessary.  One data structure is used for sending one file, a different data structure is used for sending multiple files.  The multiple-file structure can also be used to send one file.  So why not just always use the multiple-file structure?

Comment: @David If I understand you correctly,you're saying to use one data structure as a function to handle regardless how many files are chosen?

Comment: @Daredevil: Exactly.  Creating different data structures for different lengths of an array (1 vs. many) seems like it drastically overcomplicates the code.

Comment: That's what I am scratching my head now though.But in my situation,kinda like if I have say 5 files.Each file has a button `email` next to it,that if i click on it,it will retrieve it's info and ajax the data to a particular page.I also have another button `emailmultiple` that checks how many checkbox are selected(next to each file) and then gets the data and pass too. So I am trying to figure out how to fit them both in a function.Right now,they are seperate as it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, there's a way to do this.

Simply create a condition before your ajax call and within the {} brackets of the if condition, make a ajax request with your parameters. If you have multiple if condition, then you might have to write multiple ajax requests for the condition to fulfil.

This is my javascript code if i were to do it.

```
       files= request.getParameter("filename");
        url = request.getParameter("link");
        id = request.getParameter("id");
        hash = request.getParameter("hash");


//  javascript code 

if(files != '' && url != '' && id != '' && hash != '' ) {

    $.ajax({

        // ajax code

    });

} else if (id != '' || hash != '' ) {

    $.ajax({

        // ajax code

    });

}
```

Comment: There is no need for multiple ajax calls as OP has mentioned there is only a difference in data and all other parameters remain the same.

Comment: This is just to give idea, obviously you're suppose to modify code to fit your requirements

Comment: So how would you recommend best way to do this?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt How would I tackle this?

Comment: Just create your if condition and pass the values within { } of the condition.

Comment: What language are you using on client side?

Comment: Hi I am still stuck on this problem. Client side, I am using javascript and java for back end. They are all written in JSP

Comment: I used your method of declaring two ajax request but it returns Request:Error upon sending button.